# Rider shortcut for Debug.Log()?

Tags: debugging, shortcut, rider

Does "Rider" have a shortcut to `Debug.Log()`? It will be really helpful and will probably shorten my encoding time significantly - just kidding, just be more comfortable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean code snippets, or live templates as rider calls them, no, there is not.

[Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Reference__Templates_Explorer__Live_Templates.html#Index_of_Live_Templates) you can take a look at ones that are available out of the box.

To solve you could create your own as described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Creating_and_Editing_Live_Templates.html), I would go for something similiar to `cw`, so `dw`.

Hope I've been helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Rider's own Live Templates feature has a shortcut to Debug.Log(), where you can simply type "logvar" and Rider will automatically complete the code for you, as follows:

```
Debug.Log("var = " + var);
```

But you still need to change the value of "var".Here is a quicker way to log a variable, open Rider Settings -> Editor -> Live Templates -> Unity, find " logvar ", click Edit Variables -> Change Macro, select " Clipboard Content " and save.
After that, if we need to log a variable (here, for example the int value: updateCount), we can simply copy updateCount to the clipboard, type "logvar" where we need to log it and press the tab key. The logging is done quickly for us：

```
Debug.Log("updateCount =" + updateCount);
```